# Is there a way to disable "silent" Joomla pages?

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, seo

For example:

```
index.php?option=com_contact&view=categories&lang=en
```

Perhaps you have never used this contact component and there is no menu item created for it, yet for most Joomla websites you can go to this link and open a page. This feels uncomfortable to me, 'cause it means after I install more and more components, there are going to be more and more pages of my website that I am unaware of; this could be a weak point for hackers and it sometimes distracts crawlers.

Is there a way to disable these links?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **disable** all **unused components**

In the Joomla back-end via Extensions > Manage > Manage
click [Search Tools] button and select: 
Unprotected + Administrator + Component

Select all unused components (probably banners, contacts, newsfeeds) and click "disable".

Do not uninstall, just disable them.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable some unused components in Extension Manager.

Comment: This answer was auto-flagged as Low-quality for its length/content.  Please be more generous with your support with the intent to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Your answer is also rather vague.  Unless you'd prefer to post this hint as a comment under the question, please offer more specific advice.  If the question is not specific enough to offer specific advice, please vote to close the question due to insufficient details.